# Not shows two last buttons with ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I am new at android. I want the page with an ImageView at top of screen , 4 buttons at bottom of page and there is one frameLayout at the middle of page. I have done with a xml file for loading in FrameLayout. it contains ScrollView and 10 buttons. but when i run the program, the last two of buttons are not showing on page after scrolling page.

can anybody help me out?

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/yellowbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/smallyelowbar"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/> 
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/yellowbar">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/topmenu"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/more_selector"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/product_selector"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/introduce_selector"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

scrooll.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:text="@string/btn1_product"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn2_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn1_product"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn3_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn2_product"
    android:textSize="10sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn4_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn4_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn3_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn5_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn5_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn4_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn6_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn6_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn5_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn7_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn7_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn6_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn8_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn8_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn7_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn9_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn9_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn8_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn10_product"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/product_sub_selector"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="@string/btn10_product"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn9_product"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I am not sure but I think the LinearLayout should be inside of the ScrollView. The  RelativeLayout in the ScrollView shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The `RelativeLayout` is neccessary, @Day. `ScrollView` can only hold one element.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I delete LinearLayout but not shows two last buttons. I think if i changed RelativeLaout to LinearLayout, not solve the problem. I think two last buttons hide back of buttons in bottom of page.

Comment: can you post a screen shot that you want to achieve

Comment: Biraj zalavadia. I write new answer and add a picture that i say what is i want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try giving "wrap_content" to height

```
    <ScrollView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > </ScrollView>
```

Comment: I changed height of ScrollView to wrap_content by the program not solved :( How can i solve this problem?? Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is for LinearLayout in main.xml. but i don't know how can i changed this until the problem solve:(

Comment: I see Preview page of main.xml and i see FrameLayout is below of ImageView until bottom of page and buttons are upon of frameLayout. I think, i should set FrameLayout in middle of page between imageview and buttons. Please tell me how can i implemented this???

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:weightSum=4` in the last `LinearLayout` of first xml.

Answer (score 0):

Convert RelativeLayout to LinearLayout, it will work.